# Two dictionaries with some elements linked / connected and some unique

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have dictionary my_dict_0 which is defined as

```
my_dict_0 = {key_0: value_0,
             key_1: value_1,
             key_2: value_2}
```

I want to define a dictionary `my_dict_1` by copying the keys and values `key_0, value_0` and `key_1, value_1` by reference whilst at the same time being able to set another value for `value_2` without changing `value_2` in `my_dict_0`. I emphasize that `key_2` is the same in both `my_dict_0` and `my_dict_1`.

Furthermore, I want that if `key_0`, `value_0` and `key_1`, `value_1` remain the same for `my_dict_0` and `my_dict_1` at all times.

How do I achieve this?

I have seen many questions asked on this web site trying to get the answer this question, but every time it seems to end up in a discussion on the difference between shallow and deep copy. And this does not asnwer my question I believe, since I need a 'mix' of both.

Comment: A copy of a dictionary with only the first two elements?

Comment: How should I do this? `my_dict_1 = {key: my_dict_0[key] for key in ['key_0', 'key_1']}` does not copy by reference but makes a deep copy. And that's not what I want.

Comment: Do you want the `my_dict_0` to update its values every time they change in `my_dict_1`?

Comment: @user5173426 Yes! And also vice versa. So if `value_0` or `value_1` change in either `my_dict_0` or `my_dict_1`, they should change in both.

Comment: Ah, let me see this now!

Comment: You could enclose the value of `key_0`, etc in a mutable object, e.g., `dict_0[key_0] = [value_0]` and then `dict_1[key_0] = dict_0[key_0]`. Then in order to change the value you'd do `dict_0[key_0][0] = something_else`, which would change it in both places. Not elegant, but you could possibly make your own customised dict class which handles the "shared" keys differently from other keys.